# how to calculate days between two dates in oracle?

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

I wanted to find the number of days between two dates in oracle.So,I tried:

```
select to_date('03/09/2011','MM/DD/YYYY') -to_date('03/09/2010','MM/DD/YYYY') "Days" from dual;
```

the output is 365.Its ok ,but when I tried:

```
  select to_date(sysdate,'mm/dd/yyyy') -to_date('03/09/2010','MM/DD/YYYY') "Days" from dual;
```

i got error as:

```
ORA-01858: a non-numeric character was found where a numeric was expected
```

And also suppose ,if I calculate the no of days between 2010 and sysdate then the year which contains leap year will be also handled by oracle itself?

Comment: I don't see any difference between your two statements, so it is very unlikely that the first one works but the second does not - the statements are equal.

Comment: Both statements are identical and run without issue. [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_18&fiddle=f02be8c6d9c6ee86d4744782906c9b91)

Comment: Yes, leap years are handled correctly.

Comment: oh sorry i mistakely pasted the same code.now please can u review it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**you can try this:**  (sysdate is already date format so you can use like this)

```
  select trunc(sysdate) -to_date('03/09/2010','MM/DD/YYYY') "Days" from dual;
```

Comment: is there any difference between select trunc(sysdate,'dd') from dual; and select trunc(sysdate,'day') from dual;  ?

Comment: First one brings 10.10.2019 and second one is 7.10.2019

Comment: second one brings beginning of the week look this https://www.techonthenet.com/oracle/functions/trunc_date.php

Comment: `trunc(sysdate,'day')` returns the first day of current week. However, "first day" depends on current user session `NLS_TERRITORY` setting, so it may vary.